# Does Django invalidate query cache on update?

Tags: python, django, caching

I have enabled basic Django query caching by adding the following to my `settings.py` :-

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'trialrun_cache_table'
    }
}
```

Does Django automatically invalidate query cache for a particular table if data is inserted or updated? If not, How should I go about implementing this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what the DatabaseCache is. It is not a cache *of* your database, it's a cache *in* your database; that is, when you explicitly cache something, it'll be stored in a table in your db. It's still up to you to actually do any caching, and similarly it's up to you to do any cache invalidation.

Comment: I knew that it meant storing cache in the database, but didn't know that it won't enable query caching automatically. thanks